# Colored output of the input() text in the console

Tags: python, colors, console, output

I'd like to make the text of let's say

```
input("Name: ")
```

colored in a way like cprint() with the colorama module.
Is there any way of doing that?

I've tried this:

```
green = '\33[92m'
input(green + "Name: " + green)
```

But it doens't show any color. It just tries to print these characters as they are.

However with the print() function the output is colored green.

```
print(green + "Hi" + green)
```

Any help?

Comment: What platform are you on? When I run this on macOS inside iTerm, either in a script or in the IPython interpreter, or over ssh or mosh to a linux box running the same script, it shows as green. (It also leaves things green forever, because you're adding `green` again at the end, instead of doing a `\x1b[0m` reset, of course.)

Comment: @abarnert I'm on Windows 7 and running it on the console. The output isn't shown green for me . I'm aware that the rest of the text will also be green, but I haven't reset it because I'm testing it.

Comment: OK, how are you enabling color output on Windows? If you've been relying on `colorama.init()` to automatically translate ANSI sequences in stdout to console calls, did you make sure to call `init` before doing the `input`?

Comment: @abarnert Yes, I've called the colorama.init() function within my program before using the input() function to display the text. Even with that, the sequence doesn't get translated, and instead gets roughly printed to the console.